# Why is Python code generating ValueError?

Tags: python

I am writing code that asks the user for any positive integer. If what the user enters is not a positive integer, it must not accept it and ask the user for the positive integer again and again until the user entered a positive integer.

Secondly, the code asks the user for a float between 0 and 1, then checks if what the user entered is a float between 0 and 1.  If it is not between 0 and 1, it must ask again, and again until the user entered what is asked for. Then round it up to the nearest 2 decimal place.

Here is my code:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
while num1 < 0 or not isinstance(num1 , int):
    print("Invalid!")
    num1 = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a decimal between 0 and 1: "))
while num2 < 0 or num2 > 1 or not isinstance(num2 , float):
    print("Invalid!")
    num2 = float(input("Enter a decimal between 0 and 1: "))
```

When I run it, and enter a string, it said ValueError.

Do I have to use error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValueError is thrown by the `int` and `float` constructor.

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
        if num1 >= 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print("Invalid!")

while True:
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Enter a decimal between 0 and 1: "))
        if num2 >= 0 and num2 <= 1:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print("Invalid!")
```

Comment: I think, there is a problem that, if user input a float to `num1`, it should be re-input again.

Comment: @Hooting `int('1.1')` throws ValueError, so is prompted again. That is the expected behaviour as I understood.

Comment: @AndreiFortess You are very welcome! If you are satisfied with an answer to your question, you can *accept* that answer by clicking on the gray tick sign on the left. That way the question gets closed. (and the answerer gets reward)

Comment: @AndreiFortess `pass` statement literally does nothing. But you cannot have empty blocks in python, so you can `pass` to make it non-empty

Comment: But why can't I have print("Invalid!") under except ValueError: ? @hege_hegedus

Comment: @AndreiFortess Good question. If you'd do that, `Invalid` wouldn't get printed when `num1 < 0`, since ValueError isnt thrown in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to cast a string in the following way:

```
>>> text = int("Blibla")
```

The python interpreter cannot handle it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
text = int("Blibla")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Blibla'
>>>
```

Try instead to use a try/except to catch any ValueErrors :

```
num1 = 'error'
while not isinstance(num1,int) and num1 == 'error':
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
        print("You input : {}".format(num1))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid!")
```